# understanding tests using JUnit?

Tags: frontend, backend

I'm brand new to the world of programming. I'm proud to join the JUnit community, my question would be what to do or how to go about understanding tests using JUnit?

New user JUnit
I'm proud to join the JUnit community, my question would be what to do or how to go about understang.ding tests using JUnit?